# Reverse Cat Programme

Tags: code-golf

Simple problem, create a programme that takes one input, and the outputs that input in reverse.

Some test cases are [input -> output]:

```
 Hello World! -> !dlroW olleH
 Code Golf -> floG edoC
 Reverse Cat Programme -> emmarporG taC esreveR
```

Shortest answer wins

Note: It doesn’t have to support multi-line inputs and it doesn’t matter how input is taken

Comment: @O.O.Balance This one doesn't have unnecessary I/O restrictions

Comment: @Adám Fair enough.

Comment: Hi EdgyNerd, thanks for your contribution here. What happens if the input is an integer or a numeric value? There is nothing in your challenge that specifies that the input must be a string.

Comment: Would be nice to specify whether multiline input strings have to be supported or not.

Comment: Multi line inputs don’t have to be supported, and the input doesn’t have to be a string, as long as the output is in reverse order of the input’s characters

Comment: I'd suggest removing the (non-default) restriction to it being a program (standard jargon would be "a program or function" or just to remove the reference, e.g. "Simple problem output the input reversed".)

Answer (score 2):

### [Keg](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Keg), <del>4</del> 1 byte

This is in the documentation:

```
^
```

The mechanism is simple: Reverse the whole stack. The stack is in fact a string, and input will trivially be the items in the stack.

There isn't an online implementation; download the Python interpreter and run this program, with the input prepending the `^`.

Answer (score 2):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), <s>30</s>, 29 bytes

```cs
s=>string.Concat(s.Reverse())
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS7O/O9WmpdsU1xSlJmXrgOh7BTSFGz/F9vaQbh6zvl5yYklGsV6QallqUXFqRqamv@tucKLMktSfTLzUjXSNJQ8UnNy8hXC84tyUhSVNDWt/wMA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Whitespace](https://web.archive.org/web/20150618184706/http://compsoc.dur.ac.uk/whitespace/tutorial.php), 80 bytes

```
[S S S N
_Push_0][N
S S N
_Create_Label_LOOP][S N
S _Duplicate_top][S N
S _Duplicate_top][T N
T   S _Read_STDIN_as_character][T   T   T   _Retrieve_input][S S S T    S T S N
_Push_10][T S S T   _Subtract][N
T   S S N
_If_0_Jump_to_Label_PRINT_LOOP][S S S T N
_Push_1][T  S S S _Add][N
S N
N
_Jump_to_Label_LOOP][N
S S S N
_Create_Label_PRINT_LOOP][S S S T   N
_Push_1][T  S S T   _Subtract][S N
S _Duplicate_top][T T   T   _Retrieve_input][T  N
S S _Print_as_character][N
S N
S N
_Jump_to_Label_PRINT_LOOP]
```

Letters `S` (space), `T` (tab), and `N` (new-line) added as highlighting only.
`[..._some_action]` added as explanation only.

Since Whitespace inputs one character at a time, the input should contain a trailing newline so it knows when to stop reading characters and the input is done.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##K8/ILEktLkhMTv3/X0FBgYsLiBXABCcXpwInJydQEEgrADlgEZAchAFSB1KOEOEE6QICqBlc//97pObk5CuE5xflpChyAQA) (with raw spaces, tabs, and new-lines only).

**Explanation in pseudo-code:**

```
Integer i = 0

Start LOOP:
  Read STDIN as character, and store at heap-address i
  Character c = character at heap-address i
  If(c == '\n'):
    Jump to PRINT_LOOP
  i = i + 1
  Go to next iteration of LOOP

function PRINT_LOOP:
  i = i - 1
  Character c = character at heap-address i
  Print c as character to STDOUT
  Go to next iteration of PRINT_LOOP
```

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 1 [byte](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

Anonymous tacit prefix function.

```apl
⌽
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT////1HP3v9pj9omPOrte9Q31dP/UVfzofXGj9omAnnBQc5AMsTDM/h/mnpQallqUXGqgnNiiUJAUX56UWJubqo6AA)

Do I need to explain this?

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 1 byte

```
R
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/6P9/j9ScnHyF8PyinBRFAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 1 byte

```
Ô
```

`w` also works.

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=1A&input=IkhJIg)

Answer (score 1):

## ZX81 BASIC (Timex TS-1000/1500, ZX80 with 8K ROM etc... assuming sting input only) 87 tokenized BASIC bytes

```
 1 INPUT A$
 2 LET B$=""
 3 FOR I=LEN A$ TO 1 STEP -1
 4 LET B$=B$+A$(I)
 5 NEXT I
 6 PRINT A$;"->";B$
```

Very simple, enter a string (stored in `A$`) which is then transferred one character at a time to `B$` from the last to first character in the `FOR/NEXT` loop between lines 3 through 5 inclusive.

Output is shown on line 6.

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 7 bytes

I think it is self explanatory.

```hs
reverse
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7NyfmfpmAb878otSy1qDj1f25iZp6CrUJBUWZeiYKKQpqCUgZQTb5CeX5RTorS/3/JaTmJ6cX/dSOcAwIA)

Answer (score 1):

### Pyret, 65 bytes

```
{(x):string-from-code-points(string-to-code-points(x).reverse())}
```

Unfortunately Pyret doesn’t have a built in string reverse function, so you have to convert it to a list, reverse it, and convert it back.

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, 14 bytes

```java
s->s.reverse()
```

I/O is a `StringBuilder`.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##ZZCxTsMwEIb3PsXhyVbVPEBRGegACxWiAwPqcNjXysWxI98lFUJ99uAmYYhYLJ3/7@47@4wdrs7uq7cBmeEFffxZAPgolI9oCXa3EmAv2cfTY@uDowxWz2s294W6LsrBguIt7CDCBnpePXCVqaPMpE1/o5r2MxRg4rrkHdTFOk38OACaUSnEotUzhZDgPeXg7tSg@Uu2yRE8pXCcX7@NNtiiwGtOp4x1TerfgoN46BjF5clNK5N6/81CdZVaqZoSSoh6iJdqDWoZK6sjXeZ/MgLGTKJr/ws)

**35 bytes with `String` as I/O instead:**

```java
s->new StringBuffer(s).reverse()+""
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##ZY/BTsMwDIbvewqTU6JqfQAQHNhhXDZN7MABcTCpO2WkSRW7RQjt2UvWhgPiYtn@/fuzzzji@tx8TNYjM@zQhe8VgAtCqUVLsL@WAEdJLpzA6pKwucv9yyoHFhRnYQ8B7mHi9UOgzzL/OLQtJc2mTjRSYtKmUmq6Wvvh3WdXMY/RNdBleNn/@gZoFrIQi1ZP5H2El5h8c6Nm9q@yiQ3BNvr2b/t5AcIGBQ4pnhJ2Hal/V8/g2VEec6EfpKCPXyzU1XGQus@i@KBnuVK3oKpQ26U0Zetl@gE)

Answer (score 1):

## [Dart](https://www.dartlang.org/), 34 bytes

```
f(s)=>s.split('').reversed.join();
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0ksKvn/P02jWNPWrlivuCAns0RDXV1Tryi1LLWoODVFLys/M09D0/p/biKIruZSUCgoyswr0UjTUPdIzcnJ11Eozy/KSVFU19S0RpZ0zk9JVXDPz0lDlwiCmKzgnFiiEFCUn16UmJubClZU@x8A)

Pretty convoluted, you have to get a String List then reverse it and join it back for it to work.

Answer (score 1):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 11 bytes

```matlab
@(a)flip(a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z@mYKugp6f330EjUTMtJ7MASP1PySwu0EjTUPJIzcnJVwjPL8pJUVTS1PwPAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 1 byte

```
U
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/0////HkBmvo5CeX5RTooiAA)

`Ṛ` would also work here.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/) (or 2), 16 bytes

```python
lambda x:x[::-1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUaHCqiLaykrXMPZ/QVFmXolGmoaSR2pOTr6OQnl@UU6KopKm5n8A)

Lambda that reverses its input